# One of ehcache nodes mistakenly tries to connect to 127.0.0.1

Tags: java, rmi, ehcache

Could you guys help me understand why one of ehcache nodes mistakenly tries to connect to 127.0.0.1 ?

I'm using ehcache 2.8.3. One of my node is running under VMWare in NAT mode. Therefore host machine has ip `192.168.10.1` (Windows 7) and one in VMWare is `192.168.10.128` (CentOS 6).

I have following ehcache config

```
<cacheManagerPeerProviderFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerProviderFactory"
                                 properties="peerDiscovery=manual, rmiUrls=//192.168.10.128:51000/myCache1|//192.168.10.1:51000/myCache1"/>

<cacheManagerPeerListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheManagerPeerListenerFactory"
                                 properties="hostName=0.0.0.0,port=51000,socketTimeoutMillis=2000"/>

<diskStore path="java.io.tmpdir"/>

<defaultCache
        maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
        eternal="false"
        timeToIdleSeconds="120"
        timeToLiveSeconds="120"
        diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="30"
        maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000000"
        diskExpiryThreadIntervalSeconds="120"
        memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LRU"
        statistics="false">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>
</defaultCache>

<cache name="myCache1"
       maxEntriesLocalHeap="10000"
       maxEntriesLocalDisk="10000"
       eternal="false"
       diskSpoolBufferSizeMB="20"
       timeToIdleSeconds="300"
       timeToLiveSeconds="600"
       memoryStoreEvictionPolicy="LFU"
       transactionalMode="off">
    <persistence strategy="localTempSwap"/>

    <cacheEventListenerFactory class="net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICacheReplicatorFactory"/>
</cache>
```

Messages from `192.168.10.128` to `192.168.10.1` get routed successfully. But opposite direction doesn't work. I get following error in log on `192.168.10.1`

```
2014-07-11 02:02:19.260 +0400 DEBUG Lookup URL //192.168.10.128:51000/myCache1
2014-07-11 02:02:20.262 +0400 DEBUG Lookup URL //192.168.10.1:51000/myCache1
2014-07-11 02:02:21.264 +0400 WARN  Unable to send message to remote peer.  Message was: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
java.rmi.ConnectException: Connection refused to host: 127.0.0.1; nested exception is:
        java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:619) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.invoke(UnicastRef.java:129) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMICachePeer_Stub.send(Unknown Source) ~[services.jar:1.1]
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.writeReplicationQueue(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:314) [services.jar:1.1]
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.replicationThreadMain(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:127) [services.jar:1.1]
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.access$000(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:58) [services.jar:1.1]
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator$ReplicationThread.run(RMIAsynchronousCacheReplicator.java:389) [services.jar:1.1]
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:79) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:528) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:208) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIDirectSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIDirectSocketFactory.java:40) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at sun.rmi.transport.proxy.RMIMasterSocketFactory.createSocket(RMIMasterSocketFactory.java:147) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        at net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory.java:71) ~[services.jar:1.1]
        at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613) ~[na:1.7.0_60]
        ... 8 common frames omitted
```

Why is it trying to connect to 127.0.0.1 if I don't it anywhere in config file ?

I can telnet to 192.168.10.128:51000 from 192.168.10.1.

I also tried enabling bootstraping and started seeing following log message

```
2014-07-11 02:35:30.515 +0400 DEBUG cache peers: [RMICachePeer_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.0.1:18405,net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory@7d0](remote),objID:[-43892557:1472247d06b:-7fff, -5287536613776006259]]]]]
2014-07-11 02:35:30.516 +0400 DEBUG Bootstrapping myCache1 from RMICachePeer_Stub[UnicastRef2 [liveRef: [endpoint:[127.0.0.1:18405,net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ConfigurableRMIClientSocketFactory@7d0](remote),objID:[-43892557:1472247d06b:-7fff, -5287536613776006259]]]]
```

Why does it think I have peer on `127.0.0.1:18405` ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After many hours of debugging in JDK and ehcache source codes I figured it out.

My core incorrect assumption was that something is wrong with Windows node where I see the error. Turned out it was linux node that supplies incorrect address.

Official Ehcache FAQ [says](http://ehcache.org/documentation/faq#with-replicated-caching-on-ubuntu-or-debian-why-am-i-see-the-warning-below):

> This is caused by a 2008 change to the Ubuntu/Debian Linux default
>   network configuration. Essentially, the Java call
>   InetAddress.getLocalHost(); always returns the loopback address, which
>   is 127.0.0.1. Why? Because in these recent distros, a system call of $
>   hostname always returns an address mapped onto the loopback device,
>   and this causes Ehcache's RMI peer creation logic to always assign the
>   loopback address, which causes the error you are seeing. All you need
>   to do is crack open the network config and make sure that the hostname
>   of the machine returns a valid network address accessible by other
>   peers on the network.

Linux node was getting "127.0.0.1" in following method of class `java.rmi.registry.LocateRegistry`

```
public static Registry getRegistry(String host, int port, RMIClientSocketFactory csf) throws RemoteException
{
    Registry registry = null;

    if (port <= 0)
        port = Registry.REGISTRY_PORT;

    if (host == null || host.length() == 0) {
        // If host is blank (as returned by "file:" URL in 1.0.2 used in
        // java.rmi.Naming), try to convert to real local host name so
        // that the RegistryImpl's checkAccess will not fail.
        try {
            host = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // If that failed, at least try "" (localhost) anyway...
            host = "";
        }
    }

    LiveRef liveRef = new LiveRef(new ObjID(ObjID.REGISTRY_ID), new TCPEndpoint(host, port, csf, null), false);
    RemoteRef ref = (csf == null) ? new UnicastRef(liveRef) : new UnicastRef2(liveRef);

    return (Registry) Util.createProxy(RegistryImpl.class, ref, false);
}
```

My Windows node was receiving it in following method of class `net.sf.ehcache.distribution.ManualRMICacheManagerPeerProvider` where it calls `lookupRemoteCachePeer`

```
public final synchronized List listRemoteCachePeers(Ehcache cache) throws CacheException {
    List remoteCachePeers = new ArrayList();
    List staleList = new ArrayList();
    for (Iterator iterator = peerUrls.keySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        String rmiUrl = (String) iterator.next();
        String rmiUrlCacheName = extractCacheName(rmiUrl);

        if (!rmiUrlCacheName.equals(cache.getName())) {
            continue;
        }
        Date date = (Date) peerUrls.get(rmiUrl);
        if (!stale(date)) {
            CachePeer cachePeer = null;
            try {
                cachePeer = lookupRemoteCachePeer(rmiUrl);
                remoteCachePeers.add(cachePeer);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
                    LOG.debug("Looking up rmiUrl " + rmiUrl + " through exception " + e.getMessage()
                            + ". This may be normal if a node has gone offline. Or it may indicate network connectivity"
                            + " difficulties", e);
                }
            }
        } else {
                LOG.debug("rmiUrl {} should never be stale for a manually configured cluster.", rmiUrl);
            staleList.add(rmiUrl);
        }

    }

    //Remove any stale remote peers. Must be done here to avoid concurrent modification exception.
    for (int i = 0; i < staleList.size(); i++) {
        String rmiUrl = (String) staleList.get(i);
        peerUrls.remove(rmiUrl);
    }
    return remoteCachePeers;
}
```

Official advice from Terracotta is to modify `hosts` file which seems too brutal to me. I concluded that it would be easier for Ops team to simply supply correct binding address in command line of my server which looks like this

```
java -Djava.rmi.server.hostname=192.168.10.128 -jar services.jar
```

Comment: I would fix the hosts file. Mapping the real hostname to 127.0.0.1 is just plain wrong. I believe it was a temporary aberration.

Comment: My hosts file looks like this - 127.0.0.1       localhost.localdomain localhost
10.135.14.34    myhost.mydomain.com myhost. The ip address of 10.135.14.34 is valid but I still get the error - any ideas?

Comment: I was getting this behavior AND the address it was trying to connect was a public one! It might seem right to modify hosts file but you can't possibly know what and how is your server resolving the hostname. I'm just guessing mine was getting a domain somewhere in the road and it resolved to the public IP address of that domain (our website), not even the WAN connection's public IP.